# Import from one DB to another DB

Tags: import, etl, talend

I need to import data from the inner joined tables of one db to a table of another db using Talend ETL tool.How can i do that?
Iam just new to talend.
 How can i inner join the tables using condition in talend

Comment: you can use tMap, however your question is not clear. Could you add some examples to it to explain what you need. Talend provides you input components for many databases and you can use the corresponding tDBXInput components to achieve innerjoin using SQL incase you want to join tables in same database.

Comment: I just need to import some data from 3 different tables in a db to a table in another db using talend etl tool

Comment: you should then consider below (for example lets consider your source db is mssql and target is oracle) tMSSQLInput(write your sql here)-->tmap(do any transformation if needed-->tOracleOutput(to insert data)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement there would be multiple ways to achieve this.
One approach - 
Use `tMSSqlInput` (for `Sql Server` - this would change based on your source database) and mention the required attributes to make the connection. In "Query" section - write your complete query involving the three different tables -
[image]

Once done, use `tMap` (to transform your data as per destination table) if required and then `tMSSqlOutput` (for `Sql Server` - this would change based on your destination database) to write the data to your table which would reside in another database. In connection properties make sure your configure the database correctly.
For `tMSSqlOutput` do check the properties - **Use Batch**/**Batch Size** & **Commit every**.

Sample job flow -

[image]

Now, another approach could be using `bulk` feature. You would be able to use `tMSSqlOutputBulk` to output the data retrieved from your source database into a file and then use `tMSSqlBulkExec` to bulk load the data from file into your destination table in your destination database.

Sample flow -
[image]

**Note:** Always compare which would be solution would be best fit by comparing the performance of all the available solutions.